# Xamarin embedded Forms ios has additional top bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an IOS App with a Tabbar and an embedded Xamarin Forms Page with a listview.

This is the code used to embedd it:

```
contactListViewController = new Business.Views.ContactListView { BindingContext = ViewModel }.CreateViewController();
contactListViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(this);
View.Add(contactListViewController.View);
AddChildViewController(contactListViewController);
contactListViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
```

The page is displayed correctly, but it does have an additional bar on the top.

[image]

How can I get rid of that?  I tried to set it to hidden on the NavigationController. But it doesn't have one (NavigationController is always null).

How can I remove that bar?

Comment: Try to add `contactListViewController.AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the same result but with an hampered scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, to hide the Navigationbar on the mainpage not the new added ViewController:

```
        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;

        // add subview.
        activityViewController = new Business.Views.ActivityView { BindingContext = ViewModel }.CreateViewController();
        activityViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(this);
        View.Add(activityViewController.View);
        AddChildViewController(activityViewController);
        activityViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
```